# "Object of class ... could not be converted to string" in assignment

Tags: php

Why does PHP think I want to convert that object to a string?

```php
class Class1 {}

class Class2 {
    function __construct( Class1 $class1Obj) {
        $this->$class1Obj = $class1Obj; // -> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Class1 could not be converted to string
    }
}

$class1Obj = new Class1();
$class2Obj = new Class2($class1Obj);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it an extra `$`? That would be better:

```
$this->class1Obj = $class1Obj;
```

Comment: How embarrassing. A bit tired maybe. Can´t delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

To explain a bit more, when you do this :

```
$this->$class1Obj = $class1Obj;
```

What you are actually trying to do is assign the value of $class1Obj in $this->[valueOf$class1Obj]. Let's do an example, let's say $class1Obj has this value :

```
$class1Obj = "test123";
```

Doing this following line :

```
$this->$class1Obj = $class1Obj;
```

Would be the equivalent of doing this :

```
$this->test123 = "test123";
```

Comment: You are right. The said conversion is not the assignment but the left hand side: `$this->$class1Obj` is first converted to `$this->[stringValueOfClass1Obj]`.